# Insert JS variable in html string created in different context

Tags: javascript, html

I have made an instance (a string) of an html document that will be opened when a user clicks a button. But I also create a variable `msg` that should be inserted in. My problem is that the `msg` variable is not being inserted in the `document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = msg;`. I guess because of the different context.

How can I make the variable be inserted in the htmlString?
Right now I get the message: `?tempFile:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: msg is not defined`

```
 var msg = "message from outer space";
 alert(msg); // Alerts "message from outer space"
    
 var htmlString = `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
       <script>
         alert(msg); // This gives error (undefined)
         document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = msg;
       </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
       <p id="para"></p>
    </body>
    
    </html> `
    
    window.open().document.write(htmlString)
```

Comment: `msg` -> `'${msg}'`, see [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Also you code won't work since you put `script` tag before the dom is loaded, so the `document.getElementById("para")` will be `undefined`. Just put the `msg` inside the tag directly: `<p id="para">${msg}</p>`

Comment: If `msg` comes from an untrusted source (e.g. anything that a user can fiddle with: input, database, url, etc), you absolutely _**must**_ encode it, otherwise you're vulnerable to XSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [string interpolation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/string-interpolation-in-javascript/):`` `${msg}` ``

```
 var msg = "message from outer space";

 var htmlString = `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>       
    </head>
    
    <body>
       <p id="para"></p>

       <script>
         alert(${msg}); // This gives error (undefined)
         document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = '${msg}';
       </script>
    </body>
    
    </html> `
```

although as mentioned by Hao Wu you could just add the msg between the `<p>` tags. It's also best to add the script at the bottom of the html body.

```
 var msg = "message from outer space";

 var htmlString = `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>       
    </head>    
    <body>
       <p id="para">${msg}</p>
    </body>
    
    </html> `
```